# Windows 10: Join AAD with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, windows-10, azure-active-directory

How to join Windows 10 to Azure AD with powershell script ?
This is possible to do it with GUI: http://anoopcnair.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Windows-10-RTM-Azure-AD-Join-1.png

I found that there are two powershell modules:

- Install-Module AzureAD
- Install-Module MSOnline

But do not know how to use them to connect to AAD

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present there are no PowerShell scripts for joining devices to Azure AD.

You can upvote the feature request here and subscribe to keep track of updates from the product team. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20399941-all-powershell-bash-script-azure-ad-join

You can, however, create the Group Policy pbjects with Powershell. See this similar thread on Spiceworks: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2021904-automate-joining-a-computer-to-azure-ad